# iReport 4.1.1 background band

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 4.1.1. I need to set background color of a report exported to Excel.

I used the background band, but it isn't working whenever I am exporting the report to Excel.

Comment: Yes, the `Background` band does not work for Excel exporter. You can put in bands (`Title`, `Detail`, etc.) `textField` elements with `backcolor` attribute. You can fill all empty space with such elements. You can get the design similar to the one that done with the help of `Background` band.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look to the options.
(Extras -> Options)
there is a Tab called "Export Options"
there is for "EXCEL" the WHITE PAGE BACKGROUND Checkbox.
May Be it´s helpful to deactivate this :-)

BR